# Prevent destroying (or restore state) of Fragment B when navigating back from D - Navigation Component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I have fragments: A, B, C, D. I navigate A -> B . Fragment B gets and saves state from arguments. Then I navigate B -> C. And then C -> D. When I call **two times** `findNavController().popBackStack()` I get correct behavior: D -> B and B still has correct state. It works because fragment B has never been destroyed, just its view. And then view is recreated when coming back. But calling two times popBackStack() isn't recommended action. We should instead use the action with `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_fragmentD_to_fragmentB"
    app:destination="@id/fragmentB"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentB"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```

But it forces fragment B to be destroyed completely and then recreated. Bu with **no previous state**.

In other words I want to achieve the same behavior as with Activities when used `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP + FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: why calling two times popBackStack() isn't recommended action?

Comment: @Mr.AF Running the animation twice.

Comment: What if I wanted to go back 5 times? Should I still run popBackStack() 5 times? It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no requirement to have an `app:destination="@id/fragmentB"` on an action if you don't want to navigate to a new instance of `fragmentB` (since that's what `app:destination` does). Therefore you can use:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_fragmentD_to_fragmentB"
    app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentB" />
```

This is identical to calling `popBackStack(R.id.fragmentB, false)` - i.e., pop back to `fragmentB`, but don't pop `fragmentB` itself.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the class [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) to retain the previous state since it emits the data only once whenever required.

learn more about SingleLiveEvent:

- https://blog.mindorks.com/observe-event-only-once-using-single-live-event
- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Comment: I know what SingleLiveEvent is. I don't see the connection between the answer and the question